# Find whether the iOS app is installed or not on clicking email link - IOS

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking

I Have a requirement for opening the app on clicking the email link. This process is working fine when the app is installed.

But when the app is not installed it is showing as **Can not open the page because the address is invalid**

I'm trying to implement deep linking concept in my application. So if I click the link in my email it is taking to my installed app likewise if the app is not installed how to navigate to the app-store with the same link in email.

Kindly help me on this!!

Comment: You can have a look at [UniversalLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content) It helps you to handle these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Check this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content

It allows you to associate the domain with your app. Safari will handle link in case the app isn't installed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `canOpenURL` check to see if the app is installed. Otherwise, `open` the `AppStore` with the `URL`. Here's an example:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "mydomain://") else { return }
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
} else {
    guard let appStoreUrl = URL(string: "appstore.url.here") else { return }
    UIApplication.shared.open(appStoreUrl)
}
```

Comment: Hi,@Frankenstein, Can you please let me know where exactly in the app delegate or scene delegate methods this is going to work?

Answer (score 0):

If the app isn't installed, iOS won't know that your app exists at all. My suggestion is to have the email link to a web page, which tries to open your app with javascript, using the scheme associated with your app. If that fails, redirect the user to the app store instead.